# Change directory where IIS Express looks for files (C#, jquery $.ajax & KendoUI)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, kendo-ui

I would like to find a way so that I can choose what directory IIS Express looks for files that will be later processed through a web service via a $.ajax call.
For example,

```
$.ajax({
  url: destination.url,
  data: {file: myfile},
  type: "post",
  success: function(json) {
     [...]
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     [...]
  }
});
```

The content of the **myfile** variable will be passed to the web service as the *file* parameter, but always relative to IIS Express startup path, in this case *C:\Program Files\IIS Express*, more precisely as *C:\Program Files\IIS Express\myfile*.
I would like to set up some sort of baseURL, so to speak, in order for IIS Express to look for files inside a folder within my application path, e.g. *C:\Users\me\myapp\my_files*.
As long as it's possible, I want to do this in a per-application basis and I do not want to just hardcode the path as suggested [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/01/08/a-global-directory-for-iis-express.aspx) (because I am working on a development machine with IIS Express but the application will be published to a server running IIS).
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose some location behind your site(s) to house temp file. The location should change per application. I will use temp in the example below:

```
public string GetPhysicalTempFolder()
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\";
}

private string GetVirtualTempFolder()
{
    //Returns ~/Temp/
    if (Url != null)                
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Content("~/Temp/");
    else
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Temp/");
}
```

In your upload controller you need to save the file to your designated location

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    try
     {
          // The Name of the Upload component is "files" 
          if (files == null || files.Count() == 0)
              throw new ArgumentException("No files defined");
          HttpPostedFileBase file = files.ToArray()[0];
          if (file.ContentLength > 10485760)
              throw new ArgumentException("File cannot exceed 10MB");
          file.InputStream.Position = 0;
          Byte[] destination = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
          file.InputStream.Read(destination, 0, file.ContentLength);

         //do something with destination here

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         model.UploadError = e.Message;
     }
     return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```